# Number of the term

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, arithmetic

If the sum of n terms in AP is $3(n^2)+5$.What is the number of the term which equals $159$?
My attempt:
$3(n)^2-3(n-1)^2=159$.I got $n=27$ but the answer given is $21$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sum of $n$ terms $S_n=3n^2+5$ we can only derive that $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}=6n-3$ for $n\geq 2$, as for $n=1$ we get $a_1=S_1=3\times 1^2+5=8\neq 6\times 1-3$.